# Home network website tracking

Tags: network

Can my Website history be tracked by my work IT team if I am using my own home network with my work tablet?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, it can be tracked.

There is a high possibility of getting traced from a work system. but it is not just that easy to determine. It is based on the *company policies* that includes privacy and security. Employees might not be made aware of it though. There are certain *protocols* followed in every company regarding the security.

So it is almost **legal** to track every operations in your (Actually their) system.

But that doesn't mean that they can get all your passwords when using banking sites or others unless they have installed some *key logger* or *screen recorder* software. But only few of them are really hard to find where it resides in our system. Others can be found out with some effort.

So if you are wise, **do not do personal stuffs** in their system that will spoil your privacy or reputation. After all it is not yours anyway.

Answer (score 0):

that depends on the software the IT preinstalled on your tablet.

if you got yourself a brand new and sealed device which comes straigth from the supplier it is highly unlikely that your company can track you. if the work IT team gave it to you with preconfigured vpn etc. it is likely that your browsing history can be monitored. i wouldn't recommend using it for private purposes then.